# "Wi-Fi: No hardware installed". Replaced WiFi cable and WiFi/Airport/Bluetooth card. Bluetooth works but not WiFi

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, network, wifi, bluetooth

The WiFi on my MacBook Pro Unibody Mid 2012 15'' stopped working a few weeks ago and shows "Wi-Fi: no hardware installed". After searching online, I found this post here [MacBook is displaying the message "no hardware installed" when I click on Wi-Fi](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/277153/macbook-is-displaying-the-message-no-hardware-installed-when-i-click-on-wi-fi) and here [Bluetooth and wifi stopped working](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/392984/bluetooth-and-wifi-stopped-working)

Now, here is the problem.

When the WiFi stopped working a few weeks ago, the bluetooth also stopped working. So both the WiFi and bluetooth did not work. Then, I ordered a replacement WiFi cable because I thought that the issue could come from there, and then I followed the steps here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tg5gNop2Cos&ab_channel=GRIBSOFT to replace the old WiFi cable. Surprisingly, the Bluetooth started working again, but the WiFi still shows "Wi-Fi: no hardware installed". I then ordered a second WiFi cable from a different seller, and again replaced the cable. But the outcome is still the same, the bluetooth works but the WiFi not.

By the way, I tried any other way I found on the Internet, including resetting NVRAM and SMC, removing NetworkInterfaces.plist, reinstalling OS X, Apple Hardware Test and other possible fixes I found online. Nothing worked.

The paragraphs above are a copy paste of my original post that I created a week ago.
[WiFi and Bluetooth stopped working. After replacing the WiFi cable, the bluetooth started working again but WiFi still not working](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/457860/wifi-and-bluetooth-stopped-working-after-replacing-the-wifi-cable-the-bluetoot)

In the original post, I didn't yet replace the WiFi card.

Now, the updated situation:

A few days ago, I ordered a new WiFi/Airport/Bluetooth card, and it came this morning. One hour ago, I replaced the card, but the **PROBLEM IS STILL THE SAME**. Bluetooth works, but WiFi still shows "Wi-FI: No hardware installed"

The weird thing is that the bluetooth works with everything except the original WiFi cable. So it works with the new WiFi cable and both the new and old WiFi/Airport/Bluetooth card. It only doesn't work with the original WiFi cable. On the other hand, the WiFi does not work at all with any cable/card and always shows "Wi-Fi: No hardware installed"

I don't see what else it could possibly be. If I replaced both the WiFi cable and the WiFi/Airport/Bluetooth card, and the bluetooth works but not the WiFi, what else could the problem be ?

Comment: See my comment on your original question.  The connector on the logic board may be contaminated or (hopefully not) damaged.  Did this logic board suffer any sort of liquid damage?

Comment: @Allan I don’t remember that it ever did. In September 2021, I had to replace the keyboard, so I took almost everything out of the computer, but there was never any kind of contact with liquid, I’m quite sure about that. The worst that could have happened maybe is that some fat on my fingers got in contact with it