# iPhone 6S only charges from one side of lightning charger if connected to laptop through USB, but shows green charging icon on both sides

Tags: iphone, usb, battery, hardware, charging

My laptop is a Fujitsu Lifebook T937. It's a second hand laptop I got a few months ago after previously experiencing problems with my MacBook Pro Mid 2012 that [unfortunately went unsolved](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/459345/two-macbook-pro-with-same-model-number-a1286-but-different-year)

The first thing I did on this laptop is install iTunes so I could link my iPhone, use my iPhone internet on the laptop and charge the iPhone while linked to the laptop. The strange thing I noticed over time is that when plugged in trough USB, the iPhone will always show the green charging symbol, but it will really charge only with one side of the lightning charger.

When I use the charger to charge through a normal socket in the house, this doesn't happen. Do you know what could cause the issue ?

Comment: Are you using the USB-A ports or USB-C?  How exactly are you connecting to the iPhone to the Lifebook?  When you plug into a wall socket, are you using the same USB cable?

Comment: @Allan USB-A port, the iPhone is connected to the lightning charger, and the USB side of the charger is plugged into the USB-A port of the laptop. When I plug into the wall, I use the same charger with the white charger cube, like anyone charging his iphone would. I mean, you know an phone charger has two parts, the cable by itself, and the white "cube" you plug into the USB part of the cable so you can plug it into a socket. It's not a special USB cable, it's a normal lightning charger cable, I just remove the white cube when I connect the charger to the laptop USB-A port. Do you mean that ?

Comment: Is the USB-A lightning cable the one that came with the iPhone?

Comment: @Allan No it isn't, but it's the exact same model, the white cable with the white cube. I never had any issue with it, I bought this charger in January 2021. In November 2022, I bought a second hand iPhone 6S wich I have been using for now. I still have the iPhone 5S that I used until then, it works fine, never had an issue, it's just the iOS limitation that made me buy the 6S.

Comment: @Allan I will try with another lighning cable as soon as I'm home to see if the issue also occurs, but I would be surprised because as said, the cable never had any issue until now and I did the same thing (plugging the cable in the USB-A port) with my MacBook Pro Mid 2012 until I switched laptop a few months ago, and never had any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the iPhone will always show the green charging symbol, but it will really charge only with one side of the lightning charger...When I use the charger to charge through a normal socket in the house, this doesn't happen.

There are two issues that are contributing to this:

- The USB-A port that you are connecting to is limited to 5V at 500mA of power. That equates to 2.5W.  [iPhones prior to the iPhone 11 shipped with a 5W adapter](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210133) (twice your LifeBook). A typical wall charger, whether Apple or 3rd party, was rated at 12W - nearly 5x the current.
- You may be using a charge only or a cable.  See:  [Why do some accessory brands have pin 3, pin 2-3 or pin 6-7 removed from Apple's Lightning connector?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/452533/119271).

Unless you're using a USB Type C port that is Power Delivery compliant, the USB-A port shouldn't be relied upon to charge your phone/tablet.  It simply doesn't have the power capability to do so.  Obviously, you can use it in a pinch but, it wasn't designed for this.

The Type C port (if PD compliant) will negotiate higher voltages and currents (up to 100W).  However, your iPhone *isn't* a USB-C device so this is moot in your case, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer ! The strange thing is that I never had this issue with my MacBook Pro Mid 2012, I also charged through USB-A with the iPhone and computer, and there never was an issue.